Why is my indeterminate progress bar doing nothing?
In the following code, I am running a progressbar. The progressbar is shown, however it is doing nothing.
Once I set setIndeterminate(false);, it is working as expected (it updates every 500 ms and increment by 1).
How can I change that code, to show a indeterminate progressbar?
class ProgressWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {
    JProgressBar progressBar;
    
    public ProgressWorker(JProgressBar progressBar) {
        this.progressBar = progressBar;
        this.progressBar.setVisible(true);
        this.progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        this.progressBar.setValue(0);
        progressBar.setString("Loading...");
        // This is the important line 
        progressBar.setStringPainted(true);

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() {
        while (StatusBar.this.showIndeterminateProgress)
            try {
                this.progressBar.setValue(this.progressBar.getValue()+1);
                System.out.println("showing progress");
                publish("progress..");
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
    //          this.progressBar.setVisible(false);
    }

Somewhere I call that with
new ProgressWorker(progress).execute();

Let me emphasize that above code works fine for a determinable progressbar. I don't understand why it won't do for an indeterminate progressbar.

You can't update the GUI in doInBackground(); you can update he GUI in process().

This question is similar to: Updating GUI with SwingWorker. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Please [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others to provide an answer faster.
